# How to solve this error for PCB Design in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I am new to PCB designing and Started with Altium Designer for PCB Design. I have created the Schematic doc for Arduino Nano with all its components having their schematic and Footprints in the schematic library and PCB library. And I have also Net Labeled all the components in Schematic Doc. Now when I Go to PCB doc for Creating the doc for creating designing and placement of by components,
I go to **Design--> Import Changes from "filename "***( when My PCB doc is opened)*
I get these windows
[image]

Now I am not able to understand these errors and how to solve them, why they are coming. So anybody can provide their valuable suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can place a NoERC directive, if you know that this net is correct (unused pin, antenna etc).

Comment: Or just change single pin nets from an error to a warning.